# How insert data to qtablewidget row by row

Tags: pyqt, qtablewidget

I don't understand how to put data into QTableWidget row by row. I take data from lineEdit then put it into table, but when I try to add another person with data it rewrites the previous data, but I need to put it in the row below. I guess I should do something with "row"

Here is my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sqlite3
import sys


conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists disp_list(disp_name text, disp_surname text, disp_date text)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 550)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 261, 341, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 180, 331, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 311, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 40, 311, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 40, 251, 41))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: self.add_disp())
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 100, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 591, 301))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(130)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(180)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 10, 251, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 100, 191, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def add_disp(self):
        name = self.lineEdit.text()
        surname = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        date = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        disps=[{"disp_name": name, "disp_surname": surname, "disp_date":  date}]
        for person in disps:
            row = 1
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(person["disp_name"]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(person["disp_surname"]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(person["disp_date"]))
        name = self.lineEdit.setText("")
        surname = self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        date = self.lineEdit_3.setText("")

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список диспетчеров, у которых заканчивается срок"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add ATC"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from table"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from database"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Surname"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Issue_date"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter name"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter surname"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter date"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save to database"))






if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that you want to insert items incrementally, you should create an instance attribute that will be used to start with the first row (which is 0, not 1, by the way) and then increment it by 1 every time.

This, anyway, should ***not*** be done with a file created by `pyuic`, because those files are meant to be left *unmodified*. Editing them is highly discouraged and considered bad practice for a lot of reasons. Read more about how to *properly* use those files when [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

So, rebuild again your `.ui` file (in the next example I'm supposing you've generated a file named `ui_mainwindow.py`), and then create your actual script similar to the following:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
import sqlite3
import sys


conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists disp_list(disp_name text, disp_surname text, disp_date text)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.currentRow = -1
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_disp)

    def add_disp(self):
        name = self.lineEdit.text()
        surname = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        date = self.lineEdit_3.text()

        self.currentRow += 1
        if self.currentRow > self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1:
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.tableWidget.rowCount())

        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.currentRow, 0, 
            QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(name))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.currentRow, 1, 
            QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(surname))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.currentRow, 2, 
            QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(date))

        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.lineEdit_2.clear()
        self.lineEdit_3.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand. could you please give me full code with qtablewidget working properly using your advice ? So i will understand how it works.

Comment: @stan_88 **that is** the full code. Have you actually tried following my instructions? Have you recreated the file with pyuic as clearly explained in my answer? Have you read the link about Designer?

Comment: So should i create main window with qtablewidget with qt designer called ui_mainwindow and insert your code there? Right?

Comment: Just use pyuic again with the original UI file you used in your question, ensure that it's called `ui_mainwindow.py` (or change the `import` statement accordingly).

Comment: Sorry, i deleted original ui file. And even if i create new python file with pyuic even called ui_mainwindow there will be code just like i inserted in the beginning, where i will insert your code? I tryed to create just new python file with name ui_mainwindow and inserted your code but python gave me mistake. Sorry for stupidness, guess i am not created for programming, not too smart(((  thanks for trying help me

Comment: @stan_88 You don't have to insert *anything* in that file. Delete it and generate it again. As already said, those files must be left ***unmodified*** (and eventually only overwritten again with pyuic whenever you have changed the UI in Designer), you need to create a *new* script (with the code above) which will be your actual main script, the pyuic file will be used as an `import`. The UI files must never be deleted, as they are the actual base for your GUI.